# Button.Click in Custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a new custom control derived from ContentControl (it will be a container for other controls in a window), but I want a button to close it. (in fact I want a borderless window, but with system-like button to close it).

So I created the Style for the control which contains a Grid with two rows, in the upper row there's a StackPanel with a single button.

How can I bind the Click event of the button to the control itself, to raise an event, or even to send Close command to the parent window?

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Border Background="Azure" Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="X" Click="Close_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Border>
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
static STContentControl()
{
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(STContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(STContentControl)));
}

public void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ea)
{

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want here - you've created a click event on the control, which I assume fires when you click the button, what parent window are you talking about, what do you mean bind the click to itself? Why would you want to bind the click to itself - you already have a click handler? Can you explain the layout of the controls and what you are expecting to happen when you click the button

Comment: I want a content control containing a button which closes the window containing this control. So the code parts are parts of the control I am writing. When I try to build this, I get an error saying that I cannot use Click event or I have to use the x:Class attribute in the heading of the ResourceDictionary containing the default template for my control. After I put this in the header, it said Close_Click can not be found in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have created the template as a resource so it's being applied to the control at runtime.

You need to make sure you wire up your click event for the button in the OnApplyTemplate method (override this on your control).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx

So you would override this on your UC like so:

```
class NewUC : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler CloseClicked;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Button btn = this.FindName("SomeButton") as Button;

        if (btn == null) throw new Exception("Couldn't find 'Button'");

        btn.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCloseClicked();
    }

    private void OnCloseClicked()
    {
        if (CloseClicked != null)
            CloseClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

I added a CloseClicked event to the example which you could handle in your parent window. This isn't a routed event so you would have to manually wire it up in the parent control

Methinks you could also use MouseLeftButtonDown routed event and check to see if the button was clicked at the parent level - will have a go myself...

Comment: When I know, what to do, I'm like a thunder :)